# DefaultWait<T>.until behavior for polling

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a piece of code such as

```
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
wait.Message = "Can't find element";
wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
driver.Navigate().GotoUrl('.....');

IWebElement elem = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.ClassName("abc")));
```

Now lets say that the URL I navigated to does not contain that element with a class name "abc".

My understanding of DefaultWait is that it is supposed to find that element by polling every 250 milliseconds and timeout after 30 seconds. But I see that 
it almost immediately returns that the element is not present or throws an exception.

I am a little confused because, technically after 10 seconds or so the DOM could have been altered to create an element of that class and the wait should have been successful/ or could have been successful.

So the question is what is the behavior of the DefaultWait? Should it wait until the given timeout or am I completely missing the behavior of the DefaultWait?

Comment: Guessing this is the C# implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easiest to let the `ElementExists` expected condition handle this.

```
IWebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("abc"));
```

The reason your example is not working as expected is because `FindElement` throws an exception on failure. You could rework your example to use `FindElements`, which will happily return an empty collection, but even then, you'd need to add logic to handle an empty collection, since `DefaultWait.Until` considers any non-null return value to be a success.

The easiest thing is to use the logic provided in `ExpectedConditions` to do all the heavy lifting for you.

The default polling interval is 500ms. You can set the polling interval by passing in the optional third parameter, like this:

```
IWebElement elem =
  new WebDriverWait(Driver,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), // time out
                    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)) // polling interval
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("abc"));
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Appreciate your quick help. Now, what is the default polling interval in this case? I could of course use my default waiter to configure, but I am wondering what the default polling interval is.

Comment: 500ms.  Updated answer with info on how to change that.

Comment: :-) Awesome. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I am not sure this is working. On a given page where the element is not there, shouldn't it wait for 30 seconds before failing? / returning?

Comment: It does for me. Perhaps it's finding something with the class name and returning an actual web element? Searching by class name is very permissive: if the string you're looking for is in the class attribute, it matches. `class="not visible"` has class `visible`. Maybe experiment with other `By` options (`By.Id`) to see what works best.